# How to populate factory with data from service referenced in two different components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out a way to populate a factory using a data service in two different components.  The factory syncs up fine between the two components without the data service, but as soon as I add it in, the factory stops syncing between the two components.

[Here's the Plunker for the example.](https://plnkr.co/edit/bWymWPvbnTPXAgNQfcDu?p=preview)  The commented out code in the `script.js` file are two spots where I tried to implement the data service but it breaks the factory syncing in either spot.  (You can test this using the a Add button)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

  <script id="documents1-template" type="text/ng-template">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.addDoc()">Add Document</button>
    <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </script>

  <script id="documents2-template" type="text/ng-template">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.addDoc()">Add Document</button>
    <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <documents1-component></documents1-component>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <documents2-component></documents2-component>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
console.clear();

function addButton()
{
  var d = {};
  d.id = Math.random().toString().substring(2, 6);
  d.fileName = "Test" + d.id + ".pdf";
  return d;
}

function documents1Controller($uibModal, DataService, TransactionFactory) {
  var model = this;

  model.transaction = TransactionFactory;

  //model.transaction = DataService.getTransactionDetails().then(function (result) {
  //                  model.transaction = result.data.transaction;
  //              }, function (reason) {
  //                  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
  //                  model.transaction = TransactionFactory;
  //              });


  model.addDoc = function(){
    var newDoc = addButton();
    model.transaction.documents.push(newDoc);
  }
}

function documents2Controller($uibModal, DataService, TransactionFactory) {
  var model = this;
  model.transaction = TransactionFactory;

  model.addDoc = function(){
    var newDoc = addButton();
    model.transaction.documents.push(newDoc);
  }
}

var app = angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.factory('TransactionFactory', function(DataService) {

  //return DataService.getTransactionDetails().then(function(results){
  //  console.log(results.data.transaction);
  //  return results.data.transaction;
  //});

  return {
    documents: [],
    participants: []
  }
});

app.component("documents1Component", {
    template: $("#documents1-template").html(),
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$uibModal", "DataService", "TransactionFactory", documents1Controller]
});

app.component("documents2Component", {
    template: $("#documents2-template").html(),
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$uibModal", "DataService", "TransactionFactory", documents2Controller]
});

app.service('DataService', ["$http", function ($http) {

    this.getTransactionDetails = function () {
        var getTransactionUrl = "data.json";
        var response = $http.get(getTransactionUrl);
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    };

}]);
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "documents": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "fileName": "fw9.pdf"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "fileName": "Test60pagedoc.pdf"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "fileName": "New Contract Order Form.pdf"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "fileName": "TestForm.pdf"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "fileName": "readyforsignature.pdf"
      }
    ],
    "participants": []
  }
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/TlRAHxQ7YeqiF275suh6?p=preview, and do not forget to remove jquery

Comment: Thanks @PetrAveryanov - this seemed to work as needed!!

Comment: remove the jquery js file reference or was there specific jquery code that shouldn't be in there?

Comment: I recommend never include jquery.js in your angular apps while you learning angular and try things -- this will give you right direction. I.e. here you use $("#documents1-template").html() instead of angular templateUrl.

Comment: ah - gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case with the simple factory you're always returning the exact same object. As such if you add an element to the array from any of the components who have had it injected it will affect every other component.

```
// This will always return the same object
  return {
    documents: [],
    participants: [],
    unique: Math.random()// just to prove it, if you print this out it will always be the same number
  }
```

In the case with the service you are creating a new object every time; even though the contents are the same, as far as the interpreter is concerned they're completely unrelated.

```
var response = $http.get(getTransactionUrl);// this will always return a new object
    console.log(response);
    return response;
```

You'll need to create an object for keeping your synced state and update that whenever you make an http call or modify it in the app. I'm not quite sure what's the best way to go about this as I don't understand your problem domain but it seems like you may be better off keeping state within your service and providing whatever CRUD methods you need to keep it in sync rather than directly modifying a global shared object.

Comment: If there's a better way to do what I'm doing, I'm open to it.  Do you have any examples?  I'm fairly new to angularjs.

Comment: This tutorial shows a common way of dealing with similar situations: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services.  A slightly different and somewhat more flexible way is to use events on $scope (or some other event emitter) to allow your store or service to notify controllers of changes: http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/

Comment: If you're looking for further reading then Flux or Redux are very powerful when it comes to managing state in complex applications but may be overkill for simpler stuff, especially if you're just starting out.  They're elegant solutions though and worth reading about if you're interested: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts Suffice to say there's about a million ways to skin this particular cat!

Answer (score -1):

A couple things:

1. Services are singletons. "That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs" [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Factories are not. One factory will data-bind between two controllers, a service will not.
2. The syntax of your service declaration is a little wonky. I corrected it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pMjO4FzISSkWZmradSPo?p=preview) to correctly use a service the way you wanted. `DataService.getTransactionDetails()` can just be called on its own, no need to assign it to anything.

Moral of the story, maybe you want your factory to use the service to make an api call or something. I'm not entirely sure, but services don't work like how you're trying to get it to because they're singletons

Comment: It wasn't me that down-voted your answer but your example still breaks the sync between to the components.  When you click the add button, it should update in both places like my example does.  That's what I need it to do, anyway.

Comment: A service used in two separate components will not sync them. Only a factory can do that, by design. Is there a reason you want to use a service?